# Validate the input by MySql in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, model-view-controller

I need to add the validation script for the DD entry.If DD number is already exists then it show alert at the time if submit. The page is PHP-MVC so my validation script needed to add in a JavaScript file.

Is it possible to validate inputs using MySql from JavaScript???

Comment: yes you retrieve the value from mysql to PHP variable and pass that variable into javascript alert. If you have done anything in coding, please do paste it too

Comment: I think you also need an ajax for this. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: here i need to call the php script from the JavaScript and then get the result from php script. How can i call&get result of php script from JS?????

Comment: Before calling your php script from submit use jquery ajax as mentioned by @VMcreator. This ajax will call your another php script/function which performs all your validations and return validation result/message. Use alert to display that result/message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using one seperate php script to validate

```
<?php
          //db connectivity
          //Query
          //Value Checking

?>
```

then call this script from javascript using ajax

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
   function getMeStatus(parameter){
    var def = $.Deferred();    // Create a deferred object
    $.ajax({                   // Make the ajax call
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkvalue.php",
        data: {check: parameter}
    }).done(function (data) {
       if (data !== "success"); {
          var val = confirm(data);
          if (val === false) {
             // Status was false?
             def.resolve(false);
          }
          else {
             // Status was true?
             def.resolve(true);
          }
       }
       else {
          // Status was true?
          def.resolve(true);
       }
    }
    // return a promise to supply the boolean status value later
    return def.promise();
 });
    </script>
```